# Enable only one month in bootstrap datepicker js

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I am working with jQuery. I have created an input box for the July intake.

My HTML code is:

```
<div class="col-lg-8">
    <input class="form-control" type="text" id="dp4" placeholder="July Session" name="july_sess">
</div>
```

And my jQuery is:

```
var today = new Date();
var lastDate = new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth(0), 1);
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
   startDate: '-1m',
   endDate: '+1m'
});
```

But it enables only the running date and month. Instead I want to enable only July and disable other dates. What code should do I need to write?

**Note:** I'm using **bootstrap-datepicker.js**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should specify **lastDate** with `getMonth(0)-1` as below:

```
var today = new Date();
var lastDate = new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth(0)-1, 31);
$("#dp4").datepicker({
   startDate: '-1m',
   endDate: lastDate
});
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/hzjt4Lqf/)**

---

**Update**

As @RobbyCornelissen mentioned in his answer you can directly give `6` in place of `today.getMonth(0)` For ex:

```
var today = new Date();
var lastDate = new Date(today.getFullYear(), 6, 31); 
$("#dp4").datepicker({
   startDate: '-1m',
   endDate: lastDate
});
```

now it will never change to any other month irrespective of the current month

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/hzjt4Lqf/1/)**

Comment: Thanks it works...but the next month is september and i want july month right so i have to change as **getMonth(0)-2**. right? instead of changing it what should i have to do to get all time as **july** month?

Comment: You want only `july` to be active irrespective of whatever the current month is? What is the actual purpose or scenario here?

Comment: I didn't get you..can you explain?

Comment: it works in fiddle but it does not works in my localhost.

Comment: It does not throw any error. And It displays all year and all months instead of one month.

Comment: There should be some conflict in your application buddy!! If you upload your application  somewhere I can check it and let you know the problem!

Comment: I will upload at evening time then i will send you the link.

Answer (score 2):

Like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/2gro6rqp/1/), hard-coded for July of the current year:

```
var today = new Date();
var startDate = new Date(today.getFullYear(), 6, 1);
var endDate = new Date(today.getFullYear(), 6, 31);

$("#dp4").datepicker({
   startDate: startDate,
   endDate: endDate
});
```